# Print web page to PDF under OS X

Tags: macos, software-rec, pdf, print-to-pdf

Under OS X, what is the best software to convert webpage to PDF?

Would be great if I could customize the output – in some cases pages have some columns that are unnecessary to export, or advertisement, etc. But that is really optional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use your web browser's *Print* menu item and select the *PDF* button in the dialog that appears.

---

For verbatim web page views, I like the minimalist [Netfixer](http://dev.shinyfrog.net/shinyopen/) (need to compile from source using Xcode), or [LittleSnapper](http://www.realmacsoftware.com/littlesnapper/); but I think they store primarily as Images.

Comment: Thanks, are there any alternatives to that?

Comment: Ah, storing as images is bad idea.. I would need something that may let editing which parts of page I want to export. It's easier and better for layout to exclude HTML elements during export, rather than later edit in PDF format.

Answer (score 1):

Building on Daniel's idea, first view the web site in Safari.  Click the Reader icon at the end of the address bar to make it more readable. This tosses out the ads etc...

Then click the printer icon on the bottom of the reader screen and print it to PDF.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use a screen shot.

Press Command-Shift-4 and you will get Cross Hairs.  Simply drag around the area of the screen that you wish to save then let go of the mouse.  Voila, you will get a file on your desktop of exactly what you dragged around.  This will give you the flexibility to eliminate the parts of the web page you don't want to see.

The default file type is .png, but you can change this:

open a terminal

```
sudo defaults write com.apple.screencapture type pdf

sudo killall SystemUIServer
```

[Reference](http://osxdaily.com/2006/12/08/taking-screenshots-in-mac-os-x-and-changing-the-default-filetype-from-png-to-whatever/)

[image: System Preference for Screen Capture Keyboard Shortcuts]